# One class over riding the second one?

Tags: java

I wrote a Java program that has 3 classes:

**main.class** (main method class)

**Infout.class** (class that draws circle + methods for circle that allow it to be controlled with keyboard input (arrow keys)

**obj2.class** (class that draws a rectangle)

---

All the code is compiled fine, but for some reason when I run the program, the program executes all the code from **obj2.class** but does not execute the one from **Infout.class**.

In other words, it draws the rectangle (**obj2.class**) but it does not draw the controllable circle (**Infout.class**). Is **Obj2.class** over riding **Infout.class**? If it is, what should I do?

The code is much too big to post here, the website says the post is "mostly code" :c.

Thanks!

EDIT: Ok here's the relevant code:

**main.class**

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class main {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Infout m = new Infout();
    obj2 o = new obj2();

    frame.add(m);
    frame.add(o);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 400);
    frame.setTitle("Circle");
}
    }
```

**Infout.class**

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Infout extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
    double x = 0, y = 0, velx = 0, vely = 0;

    public Infout(){
        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 40, 40));
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        repaint();
        x += velx;
        y += vely;

        if (x < 0 || x > 260)
        {
            velx = 0;
            vely = 0;
        }
        if (y < 0 || y > 340)
        {
            velx = 0;
            vely = 0;
        }
    }

    public void up() {
        vely = -1.5;
        velx = 0;
    }

    public void down() {
        vely = 1.5;
        velx = 0;
    }

    public void left() {
        velx = -1.5;
        vely = 0;
    }

    public void right() {
        velx = 1.5;
        vely = 0;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            up();
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            down();
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right();
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left();
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

**obj2.class**

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;


    public class obj2 extends JPanel{

int x;
int y;

public obj2(){

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(10, 20, 40, 40));
}

    }
```

Comment: Instead of posting all of your code or none of your code, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Comment: Yeah, there's no way to troubleshoot this without seeing the code.  Just show us the parts that are relevant (the method in infout.class that is not being called, and the code that is presumably calling it).

Comment: I updated the post! The relevant code is there

Answer (score 0):

`Infout` and `obj2` are not related.

Because `obj2` extends `JPanel`, the call `super.paintComponent(g)` calls `JPanel`'s version.  If you `obj2` to be a subclass of `Infout`, then you need to use `extends`:

```
public class obj2 extends Infout {
    // Code here
}
```

Once this is done, `super` will refer to `Infout`.

Comment: That sort of worked. Now the circle is drawn and the rectangle is drawn. But the circle is not movable still :s

Comment: `obj2` doesn't define any of the direction methods.  Instead, it just relies on `Infout`, which only moves the rectangle.  You have to implement those methods in `obj2` and make sure they call `super(...)`.